# I am getting layout inflater error while using android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" in my xml

Tags: android, layout-inflater

My application is crashing if I am using `android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"` in my xml . I don't want to give hard coded text size because the I have to create create xml for different screen sizes or I have to manage the text size at run time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/title"
        android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/saveOnDialog"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/save"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelOnDialog"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Log.e output -

```
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:271)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:479)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.umob.alerts.SaveDialog.showSaveDialog(SaveDialog.java:19)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.umob.notepad.NotepadScreen.onOptionsItemSelected(NotepadScreen.java:41)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2566)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:990)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:156)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
06-26 11:46:27.439: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"`

instead of

`android:textSize="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"`

Answer (score 0):

Ishan

I would normally suggest create dimens.xml file and then from the dimens.xml , reference your declared custom dimensions here. Using text appearance hasn't been very fruitful in apps that I have personally ctrearted and with all the different types of devices floating around creating your own set of dimens.XML would be the best approach.

Also while creating a don't size always declare them as sp instead of dp while relating them in your XML

A little help if need be
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Comment: thanks naresh , usually I create dimens.xml but I was trying to use " ?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge " just for change . :)